# passing/converting Elmish `dispatch` messages from a parent component to a child component

Tags: f#, discriminated-union, elmish

In the wonderful `FBlazorShop` repo, [Onur Gumus](https://github.com/OnurGumus) is riffing off of Steve Sanderson’s [Pizza Workshop](https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop) with F# flavor. On line 128 of `blob/master/FBlazorShop.Web.BlazorClient/Home/Home.fs` [[GitHub](https://github.com/OnurGumus/FBlazorShop/blob/master/FBlazorShop.Web.BlazorClient/Home/Home.fs#L120)], Onur is passing an Elmish `Message` for the parent, `HomeView`, inheriting `ElmishComponent<Model, Message>` , to a child, `PizzaConfigView`, inheriting `ElmishComponent<Model, PizzaConfigMsg>`. By convention, we can see `Message` being converted (?) to `PizzaConfigMsg` with this:

```ml
(PizzaConfigMsg >> dispatch)
```

where `dispatch` is of type `Message -> unit`. At the time of this writing, I have no idea how this ‘conversion’ is happening (in part because I refuse to compile this repo by [going back to .NET core 3.x](https://github.com/OnurGumus/FBlazorShop/blob/2c8739a42c726f5f39c941be8f8186fdb066f3a0/global.json#L3)). I am not familiar with this usage of the `>>` operator. Is this operation actually a conversion or is something else going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find `>>` confusing, but are comfortable with `|>`, then you can easily rewrite that line like this:

```ml
fun pizzaMsg -> pizzaMsg |> PizzaConfigMsg |> dispatch
```

Since the top-level message type is:

```ml
type Message =
    | SpecialsReceived of PizzaSpecial list
    | PizzaConfigMsg of PizzaConfigMsg
    | OrderMsg of OrderMsg
    | CheckoutRequested of Order
```

This tells us that the code is converting a value of type `PizzaConfigMsg` (which I've called `pizzaMsg` above) to a top-level `Message` via the `Message.PizzaConfigMsg` union case, then dispatching the result.

This style of coding (where function arguments become implicit, rather than explicit) is called "point-free programming". You can find more information about it [here](https://blog.jayway.com/2012/05/08/point-free-programming-style-in-f/).